# INTERNAL ERROR when installing local package

Tags: installation, package, idris

I'm getting

```
Uncaught error: INTERNAL ERROR: Can't make directory foo
```

when trying to install my local library. I'm running `idris2 --install foo.ipkg` in a directory

```
.
+-foo.ipkg
+-src
  +-Util.idr
```

with file contents

```
package foo 
version = "0.0.1"

sourcedir = "src"
modules = Util
```

and

```
module Util
```

I've been following [these docs](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/packages.html) and I'm wondering whether this has something to do with write permissions and the `$PREFIX` they mention. Setting `PREFIX=<some_dir> idris2 --install foo.ipkg` didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's cos the compiler doesn't create the necessary directories yet ([fix is pending](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/pull/1300)). It can be fixed by creating the directories manually and setting the `$IDRIS2_PREFIX` (`$PREFIX` is for when using make)

```
mkdir -p out/idris2-0.3.0
IDRIS2_PREFIX=$(pwd)/out idris2 --install foo.ipkg
```

I don't understand why this means I can then use the foo package in my executables (from the docs I'd have thought I need to put them in a `depends` directory, or perhaps `export IDRIS2_PREFIX=$(pwd)/out`) but I can.

Presumably this will also mean other dependencies aren't accessible if they're not in `out/`. I've only got one dependency here so I haven't tried.